# Multiple (8) Ajax requests NOT getting content at the same time

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I am firing up 8 ajax requests (to the same link, but with different paramenters) at the same time.
They all fire (in browser) at the same time, but they return results (content) only 1 at a time, instead of all at a time.

I am starting the requests in a for loop, 8 at a time. The code is simple:

```
$.ajax({
       url: vurl + module_name+"/keywords/research/"+current_step,
      type: 'POST',
      data: tosend,
      dataType: 'json'
  })
   .done(function (request) { console.log(request);} );
```

As you can see in this picture:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIxGR.png

All requests are made, but they finish 1 at a time. Once one finishes, the other one finishes and so on...
What can I do about this?

Thanks

Comment: Your server is configured to handle only one request at a time.

Comment: use async.true and check your network tab